# Docker run rm with rest API

Tags: docker

In command line it is possible to do: `docker run --rm image`

So that it deletes the container after running.

Is this possible using the REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any JSON parameter allowing you to set the `--rm` option in [`docker create` REST API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.22/#create-a-container) or [`docker start` REST API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.22/#start-a-container).

Since [`docker run` in REST](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.22/#3-going-further) is create + start, I suspect you would need to call the [`docker remove` REST](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.22/#remove-a-container) yourself once the container is stopped.

Comment: Yes that's what I was gathering. In fact thats what I'm doing. Unfortunately there is one case where I run a health check where I need this behaviour. Anyway I will have to do it in other way.